# Having trouble assigning the correct values to struct in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read information off of a text file and use the info to assign values to my struct variables. My text file is as follows:

```
A 2 B C  
B 1 D NULL  
C 0 NULL NULL  
D 0 NULL NULL
```

My source code is as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct tree_node
{
    char *node_name;    
    int children_no;
    char *child_Name1;
    char *child_Name2;
};

struct tree_node nodes[4];

int main()
{
    char nodeName[10];
    int noChildren;
    char childNames1[10];
    char childNames2[10];       
    int i = 0;

    FILE *f = fopen("inputFile.txt", "r");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %s %s", nodeName, &noChildren, childNames1,childNames2) != EOF)
    {
        nodes[i].node_name = nodeName;
        nodes[i].children_no = noChildren;
        nodes[i].child_Name1 = childNames1;
        nodes[i].child_Name2 = childNames2;
        printf("Node name = %s; Number of children = %d; child 1 = %s; child 2 = %s\n", nodes[i].node_name, nodes[i].children_no, nodes[i].child_Name1, nodes[i].child_Name2);
        i = i+1;
    }

    printf("INNCORECT PRINT:\n");
    for(int j = 0; j<4; j=j+1)
    {
        printf("Node name = %s; Number of children = %d; child 1 = %s; child 2 = %s\n", nodes[j].node_name, nodes[j].children_no, nodes[j].child_Name1, nodes[j].child_Name2); 
    }
}
```

The printf inside the while loop prints correctly, but when I try to print outside the while loop in the for loop below, it seems all 4 elements of my struct array are the last input from the text file. The console output is as follows:

```
Node name = A; Number of children = 2; child 1 = B; child 2 = C
Node name = B; Number of children = 1; child 1 = D; child 2 = NULL
Node name = C; Number of children = 0; child 1 = NULL; child 2 = NULL
Node name = D; Number of children = 0; child 1 = NULL; child 2 = NULL
INNCORECT PRINT:
Node name = D; Number of children = 2; child 1 = NULL; child 2 = NULL
Node name = D; Number of children = 1; child 1 = NULL; child 2 = NULL
Node name = D; Number of children = 0; child 1 = NULL; child 2 = NULL
Node name = D; Number of children = 0; child 1 = NULL; child 2 = NULL
```

Any help at all on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated, as I have been stuck with this for a while now. Apologies in advance if my question format is wrong, this is my first time posting here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that you read the next line over the first set of variables.  You'll need to make copies, allocating space for each string.  Notice that the numbers are all OK.

Comment: Pointer members of the structure point to the temporary `char` array you use for holding inputs. use `strdup` or `malloc+strcpy`.

Comment: Ok I now see my problem, although I am having a hard time figuring out how to use malloc and strcpy to resolve the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use POSIX [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) if it is available.  If it isn't, write it: `char *strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *dup = malloc(len); if (dup != 0) memmove(dup, str, len); return dup; }` (include `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>` and think about how to get `strdup()` declared to your code (rename it as `str_dup()`, for example — that avoids reserved identifiers — and create a header to declare it).

Answer (score 0):

With strdup()

```
while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %s %s", nodeName, &noChildren, childNames1,childNames2) != EOF) {
    nodes[i].node_name = strdup(nodeName);
    // should check strdup() for failure since its malloc() may fail

    nodes[i].children_no = noChildren;
    nodes[i].child_Name1 = strdup(childNames1);
    nodes[i].child_Name2 = strdup(childNames2);
    printf("Node name = %s; Number of children = %d; child 1 = %s; child 2 = %s\n", nodes[i].node_name, nodes[i].children_no, nodes[i].child_Name1, nodes[i].child_Name2);
    i = i+1;
}
```

With malloc() and strcpy()

```
while (fscanf(f, "%s %d %s %s", nodeName, &noChildren, childNames1,childNames2) != EOF) {
    nodes[i].node_name = malloc(strlen(nodeName) + 1);
    nodes[i].child_Name1 =  malloc(strlen(childNames1) + 1);
    nodes[i].child_Name2 =  malloc(strlen(childNames2) + 1);
    // be sure to check these for failure via == NULL

    strcpy(nodes[i].node_name, nodeName);
    nodes[i].children_no = noChildren;
    strcpy(nodes[i].child_Name1, childNames1);
    strcpy(nodes[i].child_Name2, childNames2);
    printf("Node name = %s; Number of children = %d; child 1 = %s; child 2 = %s\n", nodes[i].node_name, nodes[i].children_no, nodes[i].child_Name1, nodes[i].child_Name2);
    i = i+1;
}
```

In both cases, you should free the memory for `node_name`, `child_Name1` and `childName2` when you are finished with them.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful. Much appreciated.